# Layout for new activity is created but not combining with the new activity, anyone knows about this?? Below is image of the error

Tags: android

Layout for new activity is created but not combining with the new activity, anyone knows about this?? Below is image of the error

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QX7Y.png)

Comment: try File->Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: show me your import in CategoriesActivity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following steps by first doing **1**, if not **2** otherwise **3**:

1. Clean project
2. File -> Invalidate caches and restart
3. See the layout, it will have some **errors** in it.